# Is there a way to set the default column layout and sizes for Windows File Explorer views for zip files?

Tags: windows-explorer

I want to open freshly created/downloaded **zip files** in Windows File Explorer in **Details view** with a **customized default column layout** that's different than the default Name, Type, Compressed size, Password, Size, Ratio, Date modified.

The default view is *almost* okay, but the filenames I work with often exceed the column size, and there are columns I never use, cluttering up the display.  It's an ongoing irritation.

Just to be absolutely clear:

1. I download a .zip file and double-click it to open it.
2. I want to see File Explorer open it with a wider space for the Name and Type columns, the Password and Ratio columns hidden, and the rest of the columns reordered to better match what I've set for my regular folders.

Is this critical?  No.  I've lived decades with this behavior.  And I know about e.g. 7-Zip.  I want to use File Explorer.

Would it brighten my day every time I open a new .zip file in Explorer if I could set the defaults?  ABSOLUTELY.  And I know Explorer can do the work - I can set the columns of an individual zip file, then come back later and open *that same zip file* again and it still retains the layout I've given it.  I just want to know what/where to tweak to make my choices the default.  I've tried using the [Apply to Folders] button in "Change folder and search options" to no avail.

**Any ideas how to achieve this?**  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the way to set a custom template for `.zip` folders is via an `AllFolders` regtistry entry. These can be per-user modifications if created under:

```
    HKCU\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{80213e82-bcfd-4c4f-8817-bb27601267a9}
```

or machine-wide if created under:

```
    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\bags\AllFolders\Shell\{80213e82-bcfd-4c4f-8817-bb27601267a9}
```

Because the view property bags are strored with binary data specifying Columns, sort, etc., it's best to copy an existing saved view that has been set to the preferred defaults. Locating the bag you want to copy is the only tricky part. You'll be looking for an entry With the registry path:

```
    HKCU\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\<Bag#>\Shell\{80213e82-bcfd-4c4f-8817-bb27601267a9}
```

---

## Warnings:

### For a `.zip` folder to use its dedicated *`FolderType`* (`{80213e82-bcfd-4c4f-8817-bb27601267a9}`):

- It must be created/opened in a folder that ***does not*** have Inheritance set for itself or any ancestor.
- Default *`FolderTypes`* must not be over-ridden by a `FolderType` entry under either:

  - `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders`
  - `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\bags\AllFolders`

---

[ProcMon](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) is one way to determine what bag is being writeen to when an **Explorer** window is closed (that is when any view modifications are saved). Another way is to:

- determine the highest numbered bag currently in use.

  - **PowerShell**:

    ```
      'MaxBaag# - {0}' -f ([Int[]]((gci 'HKCU:\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags' -Name) -match '\d+') | sort)[-1]
    ```
- Open **Explorer**, create a new `.zip` folder, set its view to your liking, close the **Explorer** window.
- The view you just created should now be saved with the name:
- `...\Bags\<MaxBag# + 1>\Shell\{80213e82-bcfd-4c4f-8817-bb27601267a9}`

<MaxBag# + 1>

Once you've located the bag you want to copy you simply have to:

1. Export the registry key:

   ```
   HKCU\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\<Bag#>\Shell\{80213e82-bcfd-4c4f-8817-bb27601267a9}
   ```
2. Open the `.reg` file and edit the key path:

   - For a per-user mod, simply replace the bag number with the string `AllFolders`
   - For a machine-wide mod, in addition to replacing the bag#, replace:

     - `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software`
   - with:

     - `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE`

       ```
         Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

         ; Copied From:
         ; [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{80213E82-BCFD-4C4F-8817-BB27601267A9}]
         ; Per-user path
         [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{80213E82-BCFD-4C4F-8817-BB27601267A9}]
         ; Machine-wide path would be:
         [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{80213E82-BCFD-4C4F-8817-BB27601267A9}]
       ```
3. Save and then merge the modified `.reg` file
4. Verify you've created a registry entry similar to the following (don't forget to refresh the view in RegEdit if already opened):
   [image]
5. Sign out and back in (per-user) or restart (machine-wide) for changes to take effect.

Comment: Hm, first attempt at adding a comment was somehow lost...  Trying again...  I went through your instructions carefully.  No matter how I edit my view for .zip I'm just never seeing any bag created under a bag number with the key {80213e82-bcfd-4c4f-8817-bb27601267a9}.  Just {5C4F28B5-F869-4E84-8E60-F11DB97C5CC7}, which appears to be just the regular folder customization GUID.

Comment: OK, I got it.  I had another tweak in the registry that was incompatible; once removed your instructions worked!  The tweak was to set all folders to General Items by Setting FolderType to NotSpecified in [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell]

Comment: Great! I'll add that info along with the warning about inheritance. As the OP at the reply I initially linked to never acknowledged my answer, could you please mark this as  'Answer'?

Comment: To be clear, you need not add anything else.  I had to _remove_ the NotSpecified tweak.  The change you suggested has been holding.  New .zip files now open just as wanted.  Thanks again!  I've marked yours as the correct answer.

Comment: You're welcome. Happy to help.

Comment: Just following up...  I experience a small pang of delight every. single. time. I open a downloaded zip file in File Explorer (something I do as part of my job many times a day) and it already has the right columns at the right sizes.  So few gifts keep on giving.  If I could buy you a case of beer I would, Keith.  I hope you have the happiest of holidays!

Comment: @NoelC: And if you could buy me a case of beer, I would most definitely accept it! :D   This was a great comment to wake up to! Thanks for the feedback and I wish you Happy Holidays as well!